# google vision API returns empty bounding box vertexes, instead it returns normalised_vertexes

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I am using `vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` to extract some dense text in a pdf document. Here is my code:

```
from google.cloud import vision

def extract_text(bucket, filename, mimetype):
    print('Looking for text in PDF {}'.format(filename))
    # BATCH_SIZE; How many pages should be grouped into each json output file.
    # """OCR with PDF/TIFF as source files on GCS"""

    # Detect text
    feature = vision.types.Feature(
        type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)
    # Extract text from source bucket
    gcs_source_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket, filename)
    gcs_source = vision.types.GcsSource(uri=gcs_source_uri)
    input_config = vision.types.InputConfig(
        gcs_source=gcs_source, mime_type=mimetype)

    request = vision.types.AnnotateFileRequest(features=[feature], input_config=input_config)

    print('Waiting for the ORC operation to finish.')
    ocr_response = vision_client.batch_annotate_files(requests=[request])

    print('OCR completed.')
```

In the response, I am expecting to find into `ocr_response.responses[1...n].pages[1...n].blocks[1...n].bounding_box` a list of `vertices` filled in, but this list is empty. Instead, there is a `normalized_vertices` list which are the normalised vertices between 0 and 1. Why is that so? why the `vertices` structure is empty? 
I am following [this](https://medium.com/searce/tips-tricks-for-using-google-vision-api-for-text-detection-2d6d1e0c6361) article, and the author there uses `vertices`, but I don't understand why I don't get them.
To convert them to the non normalised form, I am multiplying the normalised vertex by height and width, but the result is awful, the boxes are not well positioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert Normalized Vertex to Vertex you should multiply the x field of your NormalizedVertex with the width value to get the x field of the Vertex and multiply the y field of your NormalizedVertex with the height value to get the y of the Vertex.

The [reason](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#vision_text_detection_pdf_gcs-python) why you get Normalized Vertex, and the author of Medium article get Vertex is because the TEXT_DETECTION and DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION models have been upgraded to newer versions since May 15, 2020, and medium article was written on Dec 25, 2018.

To use legacy models for results, you must specify "builtin/legacy_20190601" in the model field of a Feature object to get the old model results.

But the Google's doc mention that after November 15, 2020 the old models will not longer be offered.

Comment: is there anywhere in the response the width and height? Locally, I am currently using PIL to read the image dimensions and get the values, but I can't do it in my production system.

Comment: What is the best way to watch for these changes before they happen?