# How to debug Google OCR not working on subset of group of similar documents

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I am am using google OCR to extract text and bounding boxes from a corpus of documents. I have been using it for a while now. I use  `google.cloud.vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()` and `document_text_detection()` to get what I need. Code is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62347921/google-vision-api-returns-empty-bounding-box-vertexes-instead-it-returns-normal). Unfortunately I have a specific group of Greek documents on which the text detection do not always work. On some documents everything works like a charm, the text is extracted and the bounding boxes are returned, but on other documents only the numbers, punctuation and english words are correctly identified and extracted. The documents in this group are all very similar in nature: font, size and structure are all the same. As far as I know they are all created in the same way. These documents are like some sort of receipt of payment from which I want to extract the data. They all look almost identical, however OCR on some documents just doesn't work. The language is not detected and very little content is identified.

I have no idea on how to debug this. As a user I use the google vision OCR endpoint as a black box.

How can I understand where the problem is? Any clues on where the problem could be?
Unfortunately  I cannot share the documents. Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
If I use `Feature.Type.TEXT_DETECTION` instead of `Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` I actually get all the text! The text is dense so it would make sense to use `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION`. In what cases `TEXT_DETECTION` would have better performances?

Comment: tried to use document_text_detection instead of text_detection ?

Comment: Yes, try document_text_detection. Also, what makes the documents different? Eg: Do some have images and some don't?

Comment: thank you for your answers. Sorry my bad, I actually do use `document_text_detection` I did a mistake in writing the question. I have update it. The documents do not have images, but they are PDF created from scanned documents.

Comment: your problem is expected, reading scanned documents is not an easy job, you will probably have to modify the images in hope for better results, it's not debugging but more of a solution on how to improve your results with the google-api, modify the image and see if the results got better, also have you tried to add language hints?

Comment: no i haven't, how do you add language hints?

Comment: add  "imageContext": {
        "languageHints": [
          "en"
        ]
      }
Keep in mind pointing the correct language here it's English.
And if you will tag the person in the comment it will be easier for to follow up with the response :)

Comment: Link to the languages https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages

Comment: Hey @Inga890, I am struggling understanding where to specify the 'languageHints' option. My code is similar to the one in the link in my question. I thought I would be able to add something in [InputConfig](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1p4beta1/InputConfig) but that's not the case. Do you have any suggestions please?

Comment: will this help? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364164/where-to-use-language-hints-in-google-vision-text-detection-api

Comment: image_context = vision.types.ImageContext(language_hints=['en']) 


request = vision.types.AnnotateFileRequest(
        features=[feature],
        input_config=input_config,
        image_context=image_context
    )
*If this will help i will format this as answer, will be easier to understand*

Comment: @Inga890, Unfortunately it doesn't work. It doesn't recognise any greek words. I have added the language hint as you suggested but unfortunately didn't change the results.

Comment: My suggestion is to play with the image in the demo api..